# Need explanation for some code.

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

What does

```
public object this[string name]
```

do

```
class ObjectWithProperties
{
    Dictionary<string, object> properties = new Dictionary<string, object>();

    public object this[string name]
    {
        get
        {
            if (properties.ContainsKey(name))
            {
                return properties[name];
            }
            return null;
        }
        set
        {
            properties[name] = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What you have here is in Indexed property, you can read more abou them here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/aa288464(v=vs.71).aspx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will be able to reference the values in your dictionary directly from your object using indexes (ie, no property name)

In your case it would be

```
var foo = new ObjectWithProperties();
foo["bar"] = 1;
foo["kwyjibo"] = "Hello world!"

// And you can retrieve them in the same manner...

var x = foo["bar"];  // returns 1
```

MSDN guide: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/2549tw02.aspx

Basic tutorial: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/csharp_indexers.htm

Edit to answer question in comment:

This is equivalent to doing something like the following:

```
class ObjectWithProperties
{
    public Dictionary<string, object> Properties { get; set; }

    public ObjectWithProperties()
    {
        Properties = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    }
}

// instantiate in your other class / app / whatever
var objWithProperties = new ObjectWithProperties();
// set
objWithProperties.Properties["foo"] = "bar";
// get
var myFooObj = objWithProperties.Properties["foo"];   // myFooObj = "bar"
```

Comment: what is the significant of this in public object this[string name].

Comment: As described by the MSDN docs, it's simply "syntactic convenience"

Comment: Is there anyother way, instead of public object this[string name] in the above code:)

Comment: Expanded the answer to include an example of how else to achieve this